# how mature is SD erlang project?

Tags: erlang

do you have any experience with SD Erlang project?

There seems to be implemented many interesting concepts regarding the comm mesh optimalizations and I'm just curious if some of you used those in production already or in some real project at least.

[SD erlang repo](https://github.com/release-project/otp/tree/17.4-rebased)

Thanks!

Comment: Try asking on IRC in #erlang of freenode. StackOverflow is not good for "polling the community" types of questions.

Comment: what? policies and restrictions that's what stack overflow is good at? answer my question or leave it for others and ignore it - that how its should be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project has finished a week ago. The main ideas behind SD Erlang are reducing the number of connections Erlang nodes maintain while keeping transitivity and common namespace for groups of nodes. Benchmarks that we used (Orbit, Ant Colony Optimization (ACO), and Instant Messenger) showed very promising results. Unfortunately, we didn't have enough human resources to refactor Sim-Diasca simulation engine. So, no, SD Erlang hasn't been used yet in a real application.

At the moment we are writing up the last deliverable that will provide an overview of what has been achieved. It will appear [here](http://release-project.softlab.ntua.gr/index.php/publications) in a few weeks (D6.2). In general we are happy with the results we get using SD Erlang, so there are plans for a follow up project to continue to work on it but currently this is work in progress.

Comment: Thanks Natalia - I look forward to what you come up with! :)

Answer (score 7):

This is not a direct answer but I will use SD-Erlang in a embedded application which needs to scale to hundreds of nodes (small embedded CPUs).  From what I have seen its ready to be tried out in a real application.  To furtehr evaluate lets consider the alternatives:

- You have only a few distributed nodes: then you probably don't need it and can just connect all the nodes and for name registry use either the `global` module (slow but sturdy) or `gproc`with the new [locks_leader branch](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/tree/uw-locks_leader) which avoids the quite broken `gen_leader` which so far prevented using `gproc` in distributed mode in production.
- You need many nodes (how many depends on your hardware and requirements but you start to get into interesting territory with > 70 nodes)

  - Use SD-Erlang and fix whatever problems you encounter in production, or at least report them.  It certainly solves a lot of the problems you get with normal Erlang distribution
  - Roll your own solution either with playing with different cookie values or with hidden nodes: hint you can set different cookie values for different peer nodes.  But then you need to roll your own global name registry and management code: looks like a variant of [Greenspuns 10th rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun's_tenth_rule) or closer to Erlang [Virdings 1st rule](http://rvirding.blogspot.de/2008/01/virdings-first-rule-of-programming.html) : you probably will result in implementing half of SD Erlang yourself.
  - Don't use Erlang distribution at all.  That seems to be the industry standard that for anything involving more nodes or crossing data-centers you shouldn't use Erlang distribution at all but run your own protocols.  My personal opinion is to rather fix Erlang Distributions problems than just ditch it.  Its much too useful and time saving when it works for a use case to just give up on it.  And I see SD-Erlang as being the fix for the "too many nodes" problem, its at least the right starting point.